# jQuery .text() for a dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

When my page loaded It start function to load some data via ajax. When content loaded I want to check text in this content. But jQuery can't find needed element cause if loaded dinamic.

Content loaded via ajax:

```
<div class="loaded_item">Some text </div>
```

Jquery code to check text

```
if ( $('.loaded_item').text() == $("#some_iput_with_val").val() ){
   $('.loaded_item').addClass("some_Class");
}
```

I read about **.delegate()** and **.on()** but they using event listener. In my exemple code must run without any actions.

Comment: check this condition in the ajax success mate..

Comment: You got `Some text` when using `alert($('.loaded_item').text());` after loaded (via ajax?)

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the html that return from the ajax call to html element so it will be part of the dome.
You can append it to hidden element if you don't need it in the page - that way you will have a jquery access to it.